# How to set export Path in ubuntu server?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, .so

In ubuntu, I export library path while running my scala application to load the .so files. But the files are not loaded. So an exception occurs when I hit my methods. The exception I get is as follows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzxbz.png)

I don't know how to fix this issue. Lib folder contains all those library files needed but still error appears. Particularly it shows libboost_filesystem cannot be loaded. please help me to fix this issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your libboost libraries are installed and available for the JVM. There are multiple ways to help JVM find those libraries like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `-Djava.library.path=`. Check this article for examples: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp.